# JPanel.add does not work when called from Listener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I am trying to add to my *leftPanel* when object is clicked. The object does listen to the click as it prints out a predefined sting. It does not throw a error or exception.

```
public void AddToEventList(Event event) {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    JLabel act = new JLabel(event.getAct());
    JLabel session = new JLabel("Session: " + event.getSession());
    JLabel venue = new JLabel("Venue: " + event.getVenue());

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260,50));
    panel.add(act);
    panel.add(session);
    panel.add(venue);

    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
             AddToPlan(event);
             System.out.println(event.getAct()+";"+event.getSession()+";"+event.getVenue());
         }
      });

    rightPanel.add(panel,"West");
}
```

This is the function called to add the panel. Event tho I am creating a new JPanel it is not adding it to the left panel.

```
public void AddToPlan( Event event) {

    JPanel panelL = new JPanel();
    panelL.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    JLabel act = new JLabel(event.getAct());
    JLabel session = new JLabel("Session: " + event.getSession());
    JLabel venue = new JLabel("Venue: " + event.getVenue());

    panelL.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelL, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelL.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260,50));
    panelL.add(act);
    panelL.add(session);
    panelL.add(venue);

    leftPanel.add(panelL,"West");
}

    rightPanel.add(panel,"West");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to add the panel into another panel (`leftPanel`) when it already exists in `rightPanel`. I'm not sure what I'd *expect* that to do, but it doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet to me it sounds good.to op, easy way to chack: try to delete the last line and if it doesn't work this is not the problem.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) ..

Comment: .. 4) Don't use 'magic numbers' when there are defined constants for the task.  The constants will benefit from compile-time checking, and are often more human readable.

Comment: I'd guess a call to `revalidate` and `repaint` might be in order

Comment: @JonSkeet, I changed the code as seen above but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you could post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would certainly make it easier to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @Jhonskeet and @MadProgrammer

Adding a multiple instances of the same object causes clashes. Should always use revalidate and repaint after adding to JPanel.